# Is this is a correct way to call wcf service in android?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am getting network error while calling wcf service in android.Actually in this i am using zxing library for barcode scan,and i want that the email what i am getting after scan should go to the service and give me the details of that email id..

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxCallback;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxStatus;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
private Button scanBtn;
public TextView formatTxt, contentTxt,email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    formatTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.scan_button) {
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("EMAIL: " + scanContent);
       email= contentTxt;

        String url = "url"
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("email", scanContent);
        AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(MainActivity.this);
        mAQuery.ajax(url, map, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {
                super.callback(url, data, status);
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d("###$Request URL", url + "");
                    Log.d("###$Response ", data + "");
                    Log.d("###$Status Message : ", status.getMessage() + "");
                    Log.d("###$Status Code : ", status.getCode() + "");
                }
                if (status.getCode() == -101 || null == data) {
                    //Internet connection error
                    return;
                }
                if (null != data && status.getCode() != -101) {
                    // data : Your response from server
                }
            }
        });


    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

}